# how to connect a cloud google server via cygwin for windows users?

Tags: python, windows, ssh, cygwin, google-cloud-datastore

Well, that's should be easy, according to the document on:
 **https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/gcutil/**

BUT it's not that simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. install Cygwin (32 bit!) + the relevant libraries (packages): SSH, curl, python, g++, make, vim, etc'... [as explained in this video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjxEH_tr7e0) (on minute 5)
2. install Python ( set ENV variable: CLOUDSDK_PYTHON to ...)
3. start cygwin and check if Python works:
   type python - you should see the version and the command line should change from $ to >>> (exit by ctrl+Z)
4. run curl command:

   > $ curl https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/install_google_cloud_sdk.bash | bash

   - this didn't work for me. so I had to download & extract manually:

a.Download google-cloud-sdk.zip

b.Unzip the file by right-clicking on it and selecting Extract all.

c.copy the extracted library to: C:\cygwin\home\

d.on the cygwin console type:

> cd google-cloud-sdk

and then run the install.sh:

> ./install.sh

after done that, you can finally write the gcutil command given from google (on the VM instances table, under the "SSH" button)

Answer (score 1):

@Aviram Netanel

What if you have:

```
(gcloud.components.update) Unable to fetch https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/components-2.json
```

after ./install.sh command?

Comment: sorry, I don't know... you are welcome to open a question about it :)